# ViewPager inside Fragment causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I am trying to use `ViewPager` inside a `Fragment` and get

```
03-01 15:23:05.375    3937-3937/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.SpaFragment.onCreateView(SpaFragment.java:50)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
```

Code:

```
public class SpaFragment extends Fragment  {

    public SpaFragment(){}
    private SpaList mSpa;
    private TabHost tabs;

    private FragmentActivity mFragmentActivity;
    private View rootView;

    public void setSpa(SpaList s)
    {
        mSpa=s;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spa, container, false);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(mFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()));

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        mFragmentActivity = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        Log.d("ACTIVITY on attach"+mFragmentActivity,"\n");
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Title " + position;
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
                case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
                default: return FirstFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove  `Log.d("ACTIVITY on create", String.valueOf(mFragmentActivity));`

Comment: We require your Logcat output.

Comment: i removed Log.d and still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

You are running into a `NullPointerException` because you are **invoking a method on an object that is NULL** at that time.

This could be because your

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // ...
    }
```

method is **called before** your

```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) { }
```

method, and therefore, your variable `mFragmentActivity` is **NULL**. In that case, your code

```
String.valueOf(mFragmentActivity);
```

will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @PJ that's what  i m talk in about.

Comment: i removed Log.d and still get the same error. How can i pass ref to Activity before onCreateView?

Comment: You also need to remove this line: pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(mFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()));
Just call getActivity() inside your onCreateView() method.

Comment: but i need to pass FragmentManager to MyPagerAdapter() in pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter()); i am new to java and simply dot get what is wrong. thanks

Comment: use ((FragmentActivity) getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager() instead of mFragmentManager

Comment: Actually `onAttach()` is called before `onCreateView()`. [Fragment Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png)